# Why all the vertices are connected while adding an edge in a graph?

Tags: python

I write some codes about class graph and the test result is very strange. Here I will give you some relevant codes.
This function of graph is to add a vertex to the graph.

```
def addVertex(self,vertexid):
    self.vertexlist.update({vertexid:Node(category="M")})
    self.adj[vertexid]=[]
    self.size=self.size+1
```

This function of graph is to add an edge to the graph.

```
def addEdge(self,startvertexid,endvertexid,weight=0):
    if not self.containsVertex(startvertexid):
        print("The start vertex is not in the graph")
        exit(0)
    if not self.containsVertex(endvertexid):
        print("The end vertex is not in the graph")
        exit(0)
    linktovertex=self.getVertex(endvertexid)
    tmp=self.getVertex(startvertexid)
    tmp.addLinkto(linktovertex)
    tmp.setLinkedNodeWeight(linktovertex,weight)
    self.adj[startvertexid].append(endvertexid)
```

This function of graph is to get vertex by using the id of this vertex.

```
def getVertex(self,vertexid):
    if self.containsVertex(vertexid):
        return self.vertexlist[vertexid]
    else:
        return None
```

This function of class Node is to add a connected node to itself:

```
def addLinkto(self,vertexid):
    self.linkto[vertexid]=0
```

This function of class Node is to update the attribute linkto:

```
def setLinkedNodeWeight(self,vertex,weight):
    self.linkto[vertex]=weight
```

The explanation of some attributes:

```
Class Graph:
self.vertexlist is a dict(), {id of vertex in the graph:the object of vertex}
self.adj is a dict(),an adjacency list of graph, {id of vertex: id of other vertices}
Class Node:
self.linkto, dict(),{the connected object of node: weight}
```

But, the test result is strange, I find that all the nodes are connected after I only add an edge to the graph.

[[image: the test result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExrcK.jpg)